# Angular 4/5 - filtering drop-downs according to headings

Tags: json, angular, rest, angular-filters

In Angular, I wrote a rest call to obtain the following data (I will represent it in json format):

First **equipment type** json data, for drop-down headings

```
{
    id: 1,
    description: "Head Protection"
},
{
    id: 2,
    description: "Hand Protection"
},
{...}, ...
```

Secondly **equipment** json data, for drop-down values

```
{
    id: 1,
    equipmentTypeId: 1,
    equipmentTypeDescription: "Head Protection",
    description: "Climbers helmet"
},
{
    id: 2,
    equipmentTypeId: 2,
    equipmentTypeDescription: "Hand Protection",
    description: "Climbers gloves"
},
{...}, ...
```

Here is a **screen shot** of what I want to do (but filtered):

[image]

I have the following **models** in place:

Equipment Type Model

```
export class EquipmentType implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public description?: string,
        ...
    ) {
    }
}
```

Equipment Model

```
export class Equipment implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public description?: string,
        public equipmentTypeId?: number,
        ...
    ) {}
}
```

In my **component.ts** file, I have the following codes:

```
// class defined of course
// property declearations
equipment: Equipment[];
equipmentObj: Equipment;
equipmentType: EquipmentType[];

constructor(
    private equipmentService: EquipmentService,
    private equipmentTypeService: EquipmentTypeService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.equipmentTypeService.query()
    .subscribe((res: ResponseWrapper) => {
        this.equipmentType = res.json;
        this.equipmentService.query()
        .subscribe((res: ResponseWrapper) => {
            this.equipment = res.json;
            for ( let x = 0; x < this.equipment.length; x++) {
                this.equipmentService.find(this.equipment[x].id).subscribe((equip) => {
                        this.filterProtection = this.equipment.filter((equipmentType) => {
                            equipmentType.equipmentTypeId === this.equipment[x].id
                            console.log(this.equipmentType);
                        });
                        console.log(this.filterProtection);
                });
            }
        }, (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json));
    }, (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json));
}

trackEquipmentById(index: number, item: Equipment) {
    return item.id;
}

trackEquipmentTypeById(index: number, item: EquipmentType) {
    return item.id;
}
```

My HTML **(component.html)** has the following codes:

```
<div *ngFor="let equipmentOption of equipmentType">
    <span>{{equipmentOption.description}}</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="field_issuedBy" name="issuedBy" [(ngModel)]="equipmentOption.id">
        <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
        <option [ngValue]="equipmentOpt.id" *ngFor="let equipmentOpt of equipment; trackBy: trackStatusById">{{equipmentOpt.description}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now with that been defined, I am struggling to filter **Equipment Type** with **Equipment** for my drop-down value.

For instance, if a user select the Head Protection drop-down (from equipement type), only **equipements** with the same **equipmentTypeId(s)** should appear as values for the drop-down.